# How do I change android Dependencies for SDK

Tags: android, sdk, dependencies

I am pretty new to releasing apps for android on google play. They changed their minimum SDK requirements to version 30. I initially compiled the code with SDK 28. I changed the compile SDK version to 30 and the target sdk version to 30. But the dependencies are version 28. How do you change the dependencies to reflect the changes? I have already downloaded SDK 30.

Comment: Take a backup of your project and then migrate to AndroidX. You don't have to deal with these support library versions matching with compile, target SDK versions.

Answer (score 0):

1.Hover over the dependencies and if they need update they will be yellow in color

2.Click on bulb sign on left and change it to its latest version and click sync now

3.Like this:-

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.12.1'

```
      to
```

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'

4.Also Check your buildgradle version in build.gradele(project) file